# Architecture of Gmail's attachment button?

Tags: android, button, layout, gmail

I've been scratching my head since yesterday and cannot seem to find a solution: what view parts is Gmail's attachment button composed of?

My best guess was that the three parts are separate views (Image, TextViews and Menu) and these views are held in a clickable LinearLayout.

I managed to puzzle the views together and have the clickable part like in Gmail's button working but still am missing the border and shadow part.

Maybe there is a pre-defined style for such a layout?

[image: Gmail Attachment Button]

Comment: for the border and shadow you could use a 9Patch. If you are more interrested you could read the code in this project https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see specifically what they use.